# Display Titles From two other tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a CONTAINS table in my DB:

```
CREATE TABLE CONTAINS(
    album_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES Album,
    song_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES Song,
    PRIMARY KEY(album_id , song_id)
);
```

I have two Other Tables ALBUM and SONG:

```
CREATE TABLE ALBUM(
    album_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    title TEXT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(album_id)
);

CREATE TABLE SONG(
    song_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    title TEXT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(album_id)
);
```

If I do `SELECT * FROM CONTAINS`, I will get Album_Id and their respective `Song_Id s`. Now how do I display the album names and song names instead of their IDs?

Comment: You need to join those tables. http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-inner-join/

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
select a.title as album_name,s.title as song_name 
from contains c join album a 
on c.album_id=a.album_id 
join song s 
on c.song_id=s.song_id;
```

Comment: You can simplify the joins in your query with the `using` keyword. `select album.title, song.title from album inner join contains using(album_id) inner join songs using(song_id)`. You could even go a step further and use `natural join` to automatically match these columns, but I prefer to avoid that so future structure changes don't break my code.